# Nested Structure Access in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Here is a snippet of a sample code:

```
typedef struct Test{
    int a;
    struct Test *T;
}T1;
typedef struct Test_2{
    T1 *tests;
}T2;
T2 *t2;
T1 *t1;

int main(){
    t2=(T2*)malloc(sizeof(T2));
    t1=(T1*)malloc(sizeof(T1)*4);
    t2->tests=(T1*)malloc(sizeof(T1)*4);
    t2->(tests+2)->a=1;  //LINE 1
    (t1+2)->a=2;         //LINE 2 
    printf("%d\n%d",t2->tests[1].a,t1[2].a);
}
```

I was just running some code and made this sample as I was confused about the output.
If I use `t2->tests[2].a=1` it runs fine. But in this case the compiler throws the following

`error: expected identifier before '(' token`.

In LINE 2 I have done a similar thing. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: this reminds me of the K&R example of "`Tree`" structs.. :P  
http://c-faq.com/decl/selfrefstruct.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miswrote your opening parenthesis at LINE 1 => `(t2->tests+2)->a=1;`

To clarify: When you actually write `t2->tests`. This means you are accessing to the adress of tests inside t2. You cannot access to `(tests + 2)` since it would lead to an "unknown var" in t2.